# Does equality in Chebychev integral inequality for continuous $f,\,g$ imply constantness for either $f$ or $g$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, riemann-integration

> Let $f,\,g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be both monotone increasing or monotone decreasing and also continuous. True or false? If Chebyshev's integral inequality  holds as equality , i.e. $$\left(\int\limits_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\left(\int\limits_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)=
> (b-a)\int\limits_a^bf(x) g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x,$$
>   then $f$ is constant or $g$ is constant.

*Attempt.* Since
$$\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_a^b\left[\,
\int\limits_a^b \big(f(y)-f(x)\big)\big(g(y)-g(x)\big)\,\mathrm{d}x\right]\mathrm{d}y
=(b-a)\,\int\limits_a^bf(x) g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x - \left(\int\limits_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\,
\left(\int\limits_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right),$$
we get the equality if and only if 
$$\int\limits_a^b\left[\,
\int\limits_a^b \big(f(y)-f(x)\big)\big(g(y)-g(x)\big)\,\mathrm{d}x\right]\mathrm{d}y=0.$$
Since $\big(f(y)-f(x)\big)\big(g(y)-g(x)\big)$ is $\geqslant 0$ and continuous we get that for all $x,\,y\in [a,b]$:
$$\big(f(y)-f(x)\big)\big(g(y)-g(x)\big)=0$$
i.e. $f(y)=f(x)$ or $g(y)=g(x)$, which doesn't mean that either $f$ or $g$ is constant. May we conclude that the answer is "false"? What would a counterexample be in that case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one function must be constant if $(f(y)-f(x))(g(y)-g(x))=0$ for all $x,y \in [a,b]$ and $f,g$ are both monotone.

Suppose WLOG $f$ and $g$ are both monotone increasing and $f$ is not constant.  There exist $a \leqslant x_1 < x_2 \leqslant b$ such that $f(x_2) - f(x_1) > 0$. This implies that $g(x_2) - g(x_1) = 0$ and $g(x_1) = g(x) = g(x_2)$ for all $x \in [x_1,x_2]$ by monotonicity.

However, by monotonicity $f(b) - f(a) > 0$ since $b\geqslant x_2$ and $a \leqslant x_1$.  Hence, we must have $g(a) = g(b) = g(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and $g$ must be constant.

Comment: "Hence, we must have $g(a) = g(b) = g(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and $g$ must be constant". How do make this conclusion?

Comment: Since $f(b) - f(a) > 0$ and $(f(b)-f(a))(g(b) - g(a)) = 0$ we must  have $g(b) - g(a) = 0$.  Thus $g(a) = g(b)$.  Since $g$ is monotone increasing, if $a < x < b$ then $g(a) \leqslant g(x) \leqslant g(b) = g(a)$.  This can only mean that $g(x) = g(a) = g(b)$.